# SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name while migrating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, railstutorial.org

I am currently following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial and I am at https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#sec-administrative_users Every time I run bundle exec rake db:migrate I get the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: remember_digest: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD   "remember_digest" varchar/home/mclacs14/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

Comment: so what does that tell you?  if your schema already has it then you have an extra migration somewhere trying to add the column.

Comment: Can you try migrating your DB to version=0 and then run "rake db:migrate"

Comment: Or go to the migration you want to run and delete line that generates `remember_digest` column.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try migrating your DB to version=0
with command: `rake db:migrate VERSION=0`

and then run 
`rake db:migrate`

Comment: @RoryPerro this answer will help you understand better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13333716/2545197

Comment: @Abhinay you should now you are awesome

Comment: DISCLAIMER - this command will delete the content of your database by remodeling from scratch the structure of your DB. I just deleted a 2 year old local development DB with thousands of datas ^^