# Re-migrating after running "rake db:migrate VERSION=0"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I created a migration named `AddEntryTOMembers entry:decimal`. Then I needed to change the decimal to integer. When I ran `rake db:rollback`, it rolled back successfully but when I retried running `rails g AddEntryTOMembers entry:integer` it shows:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: entry: ALTER TABLE "members" ADD "
entry" integerc:/Sites/roomapp/db/migrate/20150216143625_add_entry_to_members.rb
:3:in `change'
c:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Then I searched on Stack Overflow and found "[SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name while migrating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830727/sqlite3sqlexception-duplicate-column-name-while-migrating)". After that I ran `rake db:migrate VERSION=0`
and it rolled back all the migrations.
But when I ran `rake db:migrate` again it shows a problem with my previous successful adding migration.

```
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: image: ALTER TABLE "members" ADD "
image" varcharc:/Sites/roomapp/db/migrate/20150206144138_add_image_to_members.rb
:3:in `change'
c:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How do I re-migrate all of my migrations?

Comment: you have two migrations adding image to the members table.  find one of them and remove that line from the migration.

Comment: I am conform that adding image has one migration but still it is showing this