# Getting "Duplicate Column name" when trying to add a column in sequelize using migration

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, migration

I am **trying to add column 'player_id' to table in a migration**, but getting error 'duplicate column name'.

My migration skeleton for this: -

```
module.exports = {
   up (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(t => {
    return queryInterface.addColumn('Attackings', 'player_id',{
      type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER
    }, { transaction: t });
  });
  },

   down (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(t => {
      return queryInterface.removeColumn('Attackings', 'player_id', { transaction: t });
    });
  }
};
```

My Attacking Model :-

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Attacking extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  Attacking.init({
    player_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    club: DataTypes.STRING,
    position: DataTypes.STRING,
    assists: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    corner_taken: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    offsides: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    dribbles: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    match_played: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Attacking',
  });
  return Attacking;
};
```

As we can see column player_id doesn't already exists in table.

Error I am getting:- **ERROR: Duplicate column name 'player_id'**

Comment: You don't see it in the model but what about the table itself? Did you look at ut?

Comment: Yes i checked table also, there is no column named player_id. I have another table player, and i have created it using migration, but that was a separate migration, maybe because of that i am getting this problem, hence i named the column as 'playerid' now its working.

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333580/duplicate-column-name-error-when-running-migration