# How do I fix 'duplicate column name error' when trying to do a migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I changed a migration file being run as I made a spelling mistake.

```
bin/rails generate migration AdStatusToComments status:string
```

was supposed to be 'AddStatus...'

I proceeded to change the file name generated and added a column manually.

As follows:
20230717083032_**add**_status_to_comments

```
class AddStatusToComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    **add_column :articles, :status, :string**
  end
end
```

Thought this would fix it after running db:migrate but didn't happen.

Received this error:

```
$ bin/rails db:migrate
== 20230717083032 AddStatusToComments: migrating ==============================
-- add_column(:articles, :status, :string)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: status
C:/blog/db/migrate/20230717083032_add_status_to_comments.rb:3:in `change'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: status
C:/blog/db/migrate/20230717083032_add_status_to_comments.rb:3:in `change'
```

Tried a rake db:reset but got 'Permission Denied' [as suggested by this post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333580/duplicate-column-name-error-when-running-migration)

Sorry if this has a simple solution. New to rails.

Comment: Sounds like a previous migration has already been run with that column. Just delete the new migration.

Comment: you ran the migration first as `AdStatusToComments` then you ran it again as `AddStatusToComments` so you tried to add the field twice... hence the error. Change the filename and class back to `ad_...` and `AdStatus...`, and don't worry about the spelling problem. Don't delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

> bin/rails db:rollback

This will delete the changes made from the last migration. After running the above command, delete the last migration file which will be present in **db/migrate**.

Answer (score 0):

Running `rake db:migrate:status` will give you the current state of your migrations.

If `AdStatusToComments` is "up", it will explain why you are getting the error `... duplicate column name: status`-- the original migration ran up but wasn't rolled back.

As @koil mentioned, you can roll it back.

In the future-- don't edit migrations files that are in an "up" state (or have been checked into source control!)